# R: find nearest index

Tags: r, vectorization, nearest-neighbor

I have two vectors with a few thousand points, but generalized here:

```
A <- c(10, 20, 30, 40, 50)
b <- c(13, 17, 20)
```

How can I get the indicies of `A` that are *nearest* to `b`? The expected outcome would be `c(1, 2, 2)`.

I know that `findInterval` can only find the first occurrence, and not the nearest, and I'm aware that `which.min(abs(b[2] - A))` is getting warmer, but I can't figure out how to vectorize it to work with long vectors of both `A` and `b`.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can just put your code in a sapply. I think this has the same speed as a for loop so isn't technically vectorized though:

```
sapply(b,function(x)which.min(abs(x - A)))
```

Comment: Do note that `which.min()` only returns the first match. There might be other elements that are equally close.

Answer (score 11):

FindInterval gets you very close. You just have to pick between the offset it returns and the next one:

```
#returns the nearest occurence of x in vec
nearest.vec <- function(x, vec)
{
    smallCandidate <- findInterval(x, vec, all.inside=TRUE)
    largeCandidate <- smallCandidate + 1
    #nudge is TRUE if large candidate is nearer, FALSE otherwise
    nudge <- 2 * x > vec[smallCandidate] + vec[largeCandidate]
    return(smallCandidate + nudge)
}

nearest.vec(b,A)
```

returns (1,2,2), and should comparable to FindInterval in performance.

Comment: Really useful, thank you. I'm surprised that there isn't something to do this in base. Which probably means that there is and I'm not aware of it...!

Answer (score 0):

Here's a solution that uses R's often overlooked `outer` function. Not sure if it'll perform better, but it does avoid `sapply`.

```
A <- c(10, 20, 30, 40, 50)
b <- c(13, 17, 20)

dist <- abs(outer(A, b, '-'))
result <- apply(dist, 2, which.min)

# [1] 1 2 2
```