# R: calling a matrix value of column 2 dependent on the value of column 1

Tags: r, matrix, indexing

I admit that I am totally new to R and have a few beginner's problems;

my problem is the following:
I have quite a long matrix TEST of length 5000 with 2 columns (column 1 = time; column 2 = concentration of a species).

I want to use the right concentration values for calculation of propensities in stochastic simulations.
I already have an alogrithm that gives me the simulation time t_sim; what I would need is a line of code that gives the respective concentration value at t= t_sim;

also: the time vector might have a big step size so that t_sim would have to be rounded to a bigger value in order to call the respective concentration value.

I know this probably quite an easy problem but I really do not see the solution in R.

Best wishes and many thanks,
Arne

Comment: can you post there `dput(head(yourmatrix,20))` as well as the first 20 values of `t_sim`?

Answer (score 0):

Without sample data this answer is kind of a shot in the dark, but I think that this might work:

```
t_conc <- TEST[which.min(abs(t_sim-TEST[,1])),2]
```

where `TEST` is the matrix with two columns as described in the OP and the output `t_conc` is the concentration that corresponds to the value of `time` in the matrix that is closest to the input value `t_sim`.

Answer (score 0):

Here's another shot in the dark:

```
set.seed(1);
N <- 20; test <- matrix(c(sort(sample(100,N)),rnorm(N,0.5,0.2)),N,dimnames=list(NULL,c('time','concentration')));
test;
##       time concentration
##  [1,]    6    0.80235623
##  [2,]   16    0.57796865
##  [3,]   19    0.37575188
##  [4,]   20    0.05706002
##  [5,]   27    0.72498618
##  [6,]   32    0.49101328
##  [7,]   34    0.49676195
##  [8,]   37    0.68876724
##  [9,]   43    0.66424424
## [10,]   57    0.61878026
## [11,]   58    0.68379547
## [12,]   61    0.65642726
## [13,]   62    0.51491300
## [14,]   63    0.10212966
## [15,]   67    0.62396515
## [16,]   83    0.48877425
## [17,]   86    0.46884090
## [18,]   88    0.20584952
## [19,]   89    0.40436999
## [20,]   97    0.58358831
t_sim <- 39;
test[findInterval(t_sim,test[,'time']),'concentration'];
## concentration
##     0.6887672
```

Note that [`findInterval()`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/findInterval.html) returns the index of the *lesser* `time` value if `t_sim` falls between two `time` values, as my example shows. If you want the *greater*, you need a bit more work:

```
i <- findInterval(t_sim,test[,'time']);
if (test[i,'time'] != t_sim && i < nrow(test)) i <- i+1;
test[i,'concentration'];
## concentration
##     0.6642442
```

If you want the nearest, see [R: find nearest index](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10160400/r-find-nearest-index).