# Match events with weather data

Tags: r

I have a list with event and times. So a little like this df:

```
event <- c("x", "y")
date <- c("12-12-2014", "13-12-2014")
time <- c("11:00", "14:00")

df_event <- data.frame(event, date, time)
```

What I would like to do now is match these events with weather data. Thing is however that the timestamps from the weather I have do not match the event dates. They are like:

```
date <- c("12-12-2014", "12-12-2015")
time <- c("12:00", "14:00")
degrees <- c(12, 13)

df_weather <- data.frame(date,time, degrees)
```

Does anybody have suggestions on how I can easily match the so I can the weather data that is closest to the event?

Comment: what is expected output and what have you tried

Comment: As suggested below, you are required to merge and convert the timestamps to proper `POSIX*` objects on which you can subsequently perform `difftime` (or simply `-`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like a duplicate of this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10160400/r-find-nearest-index).  Adapting one of those answers for you:

```
#First, convert your date+time into POSIXct so that we have an index to search
df_event$date2 <- as.POSIXct(strptime(paste(df_event$date, df_event$time),
                             format = "%d-%m-%Y %H:%M"))
df_weather$datePXct <- as.POSIXct(strptime(paste(df_weather$date, df_weather$time), 
                                  format = "%d-%m-%Y %H:%M"))

#Find variables in df_weather that match timestamp in df_event
df_event <- cbind(df_event, event.degrees = df_weather[ unlist(sapply((df_event$date2), 
                 function(x) which.min(abs(x - df_weather$datePXct))) ), c("degrees")]) 

df_event
#  event       date  time               date2 event.degrees
#1     x 12-12-2014 11:00 2014-12-12 11:00:00            12
#2     y 13-12-2014 14:00 2014-12-13 14:00:00            12
```